# Why is this anti-symmetry?

Tags: analysis

In his *Analysis I*, Tao mentions the following order property of rationals as anti-symmetric (Proposition 4.2.9 (b)) . "(Order is anti-symmetric) One has $x<y \text{ iff } y>x$" for all $x,y\in\mathbb{Q}$.

What is anti-symmetric about it? I thought that for a relation $R$ anti symmetry was “$aRb$ and $bRa$ implies $a=b$”

Comment: Where exactly did you find that?

Comment: I believe he means that $x\lt y$ and $y\lt x$ cannot hold simultaneously.

Comment: @G.Chiusole Proposition 4.2.9

Comment: It simply means that if one is true the other must be false. It does not seem to align with the definition of antisymmetric relation. But the relations < and > have a "symmetery" (or rather anti-symmetry) to them in that if (x<y) we know (y<x). So every relation that is true under < is false if instead you use > (and vice versa... if you switch the symbols. however,  x < y being false does not imply y < x; because x may equal y)

Comment: $x < y$ and $y < x$ *DOES* imply that $x=y$.  It also implies the moon is made of green cheese.  A false premise implies everything.  So a false premise implies $x = y$.  And both $x< y$ and $y < x$ being true simultaneously *is* a false premise.  So every single time (all zero of them) when both $x < y$ and $y < x$ then not only is $x=y$, but the moon is also made of green cheese and I am Batman.  That's happened zero times in the history of the universe and it will happen all zero times $x< y$ and $y < x$.

Comment: @fleablood. This is easily misread, but it does not say $x<y$ and $y<x$, it says x less than y and y greater than x, which are logically equivalent. It is talking about the particular relations, which is why it is written differently

Comment: Of course $x<y$ is equivalent to $y > x$.  And that is why  $<$ is antisymmetric.  If $x < y$ and $y< x$ then both $x < y$ and $x > y$ occur at the same time.  But trichotomy says that's impossible.  So $x< y$ and $y< x$ can't both occur at the same time.  Because $x < y$ and $x > y$ can't be both occur at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

The set $\textbf{Q}$ is linearly ordered. This means that the relation ''$\leq$'' is reflexive, anti-symmetric and transitive. More precisely,

(a) if $x\in\textbf{Q}$, then $x\leq x$ (reflexive)

(b) if $x,y\in\textbf{Q}$ and $x\leq y$ and $y\leq x$, then $x = y$ (anti-symmetric)

(c) if $x,y,z\in\textbf{Q}$, $x\leq y$ and $y\leq z$, then $x\leq z$ (transitive)

However, as far as I have understood, when he says that $x < y$ iff $y > x$, he means that both notations have the same meaning.

Comment: So do you agree with me that you don't see any anti-symmetry here?

Comment: It's antisymmetric because $x < y$ and $y < x$ either never happens or only happens if $x = y$.  But as $x< y$ and $y < x$ never happens the issue of whether it happens with $x = y$ is mote.  It never happens.  So $<$ is anti-symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

Anti symmetric means that the only time $x < y$ and $y < x$ can ever happen is if $x = y$.

And as $x < y$ and $y < x$ *never* happens, that is vacuously true.   The only time $x < y$ and $y < x$ happens is .... never.

So it is anti-symmetric.

If you want to argue that $x < y$ and $y< x\not \implies x=y$.  I will remind you that $x < y$ and $y < x$ is *FALSE* and *FALSE* $\implies$ *EVERYTHING*.

So $y < x$ and $y< x\implies x = y$.  And $y< x$ and $y < x\implies$ pigs fly.

Comment: I'm not asking that. I'm asking what is anti-symmetric about "$x<y$ iff $y>x$." Your answer addresses something else.

Comment: If $x<y \iff y > x$ and $>$ the "<" is antisymmetric if and only if ">" is anti-symmetric.  And they are both obviously antisymmetric.

Comment: I think I got your point. Thanks!